# Adding a view to the window hierarchy

Tags: swift, xcode6, viewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am trying to create a pause screen on my game. I have added a 'PauseScreen' viewController in my storyboard with the Storyboard ID and Restoration ID set as "PauseScreenID" and to move to the pause screen I have have created the function in "GameScene" :

```
func pauseSceenTransition(){

    let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PauseScreenID") as UIViewController

    let currentViewController = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)

    currentViewController.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

However when the it gets called, I get the error :

Warning: Attempt to present <*AppName*.PauseScreen: 0x7fae61fe5ff0> on <*AppName*.StartScreenViewController: 0x7fae61f79980> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

The "StartScreenViewController" is the view controller for my start screen and is the initial view controller. It then goes to the "GameScene" which is where the "PauseScreen" needs to go. It works if I make the initial view controller the "GameViewController"/"GameScene" so I presume that I need to change the second line:

```
let currentViewController = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
```

so that it is presenting the "PauseScreen" on the "GameViewController", not on the "StartScreenViewController" but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what's going on.

`Warning: Attempt to present <AppName.PauseScreen: 0x7fae61fe5ff0> on <AppName.StartScreenViewController: 0x7fae61f79980> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

`(UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController` is pointing to an instance of `StartScreenViewController`. This is bad: `rootViewController` should point to an instance of `GameScene`.

The root cause must be how `GameScene` is presented. From your description:

> The "StartScreenViewController" is the view controller… It then goes to the "GameScene"…

This must be where your problem is. How do you go to `GameScene` from `StartScreenViewController`?

My guess is that you are adding a new window to the application. You need to set the `rootViewController` instead.

```
let gameScene = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameSceneID") as UIViewController
let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = gameScene
```

When you go back to the start screen, you again set the `rootViewController`.

```
let initialViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as UIViewController
let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
```

---

You can use [`transitionFromViewController(,toViewController:, duration:, options:, animations:, completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:) to animate setting the root view controller.

Comment: Hi, I am having trouble with this same issue now, and am curious as to if the solutions have changed over the past year and a half. I am trying to call a `UIAlertController` from within a nested `if` inside of a button. The regular `if` statements within the button display the `UIAlertView`'s fine, but the `true` results of those if statements throw the same error above.

Comment: @Ethan Sometimes you need to create a window to put a `UIAlertController` into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554894/how-to-present-uialertcontroller-when-not-in-a-view-controller

Comment: Anything you know of that is written in swift?

Comment: @JefferyThomas Great man you are the saviour!! Last three days I searching solution for this issue. Thank you so much.