# How to fix "error view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, viewcontroller

I have a class `PopUpViewController` that access class `MessageController` method `handleLogout()` with sharedInstance `static let`. But when the method is accessed and I try to present another view controller (`loginController`), I get this warning in console:

> "error view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Can someone help?

```
class PopUpViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var logOutButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("Logout", for: UIControlState())
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(logOut), for:.touchUpInside)
        button.tintColor = .white
        return button
    }()

    func logOut(){
        removeAnimate()
        MessageController.sharedInstance.handleLogout()
    }
    ...
}
```

MessageController

```
class MessageController: UITableViewController{
    static let sharedInstance = MessageController()

    func handleLogout(){
        do {
            try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()
        }catch let logoutError{
            print(logoutError)
        }
        // to je za ime na vrhu ob prijavi nastavi se vrednost
        let loginController = LoginController()
        loginController.messagesController = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut() // google logout

        self.present(loginController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: refer this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27608338/adding-a-view-to-the-window-hierarchy.

Comment: where would you like to call this method? the earliest point is in the `-viewDidAppear(_:)`, because before the presenter view is not in the view hierarchy, that that is why you get the warning.

Comment: It seems as if the `MessageController` instance you create as the `sharedInstance` variable doesn't get presented.

Comment: @holex i don't want to call it in viewDidAppear(_:) because then it will automatically log out. That is why I create an sharedInstance... Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: @PhillipMills What do you mean ? I call it in func logOut in PopUpViewController

Comment: @Moonwalker4z, unfortunately you __cannot__ call earlier in the view lifecycle; you may need to redesign your workflow this or that way.

Comment: @holex I even tried this, but it didn't work
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.present(loginController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }

Comment: @Moonwalker4z, it is not a threading problem, you are already on the _main_ thread but at the _wrong_ time; you need to 'wait' for the view controller goes into to view hierarchy and then you can use it as a _presenter_ – that happens from `-viewDidAppear(_:)` and stays until the `-viewWillDisappear(_:)` invoked, therefore the earliest_ point_ when you can present your content is inside the `–viewDidAppear(_:)`.

Comment: @holex Yes I understand but I don't know how to implement this in the whey that it would work similar as now. If i present loginController on view did appear it will always go to loginController but I want it to be triggered at button click.

Comment: @Moonwalker4z  I see that you call a method on your `MessageController`'s  shared instance but I don't see anywhere that you display the shared instance.