# UIalertController before segue

Tags: uialertcontroller

I want to go to the former page by using this code but I can't. Appreciate if you give me an answer!!

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

```
if segue.identifier == "edit"{


    let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ScoreBoardVC

    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    destViewController.matches = matches[indexPath.row]



    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Want to edit?", message: "Keep in mind the date!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

   presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)


}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sourceViewController` is likely to be exiting the view hierarchy after a segue, so if a controller is presented there, it will be dismissed immediately.

The `destinationViewController` may not be present in the view hierarchy by prepareForSegue there, so if you present it there, you may get

```
2016-08-23 10:22:22.354 Foo[589:137407] Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x17eb0e00> on <Foo.DestinationViewController: 0x177e7b60> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

2016-08-23 10:22:22.904 Foo[589:137407] Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UIAlertController: 0x17eb0e00>)
```

One possibility is to add an ivar onto your destinationViewController like so.

```
class DestinationViewController: UIViewController {
    var presentWhenAppearing: UIViewController? = nil

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if let p = presentWhenAppearing {
            self.presentViewController(p, animated: true, completion: nil)
            presentWhenAppearing = nil
        }
    }
}
```

which can then be used inside `prepareForSegue` as follows

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "myIdentifier" {

        guard let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? DestinationViewController else {
            fatalError("Unexpected VC")
        }

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "You are currently offline", message: "but your download willl be begin and continue when you have an internet connection.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        destinationVC.presentWhenAppearing = alert

    }
}
```

See also [How to present UIAlertController when not in a view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554894/how-to-present-uialertcontroller-when-not-in-a-view-controller?rq=1) for other answers that might work here.