# UIAlertController status bar not dimming and tint color issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, ios9, uialertcontroller

I am migrating from using `UIAlertView` to the `UIAlertController` introduced in iOS 8.  However, I am seeing a few strange view issues I don't see when using `UIAlertView`.  First, when displaying an alert, the status bar text doesn't dim:

[image: Status bar not dimmed]

Also, after displaying the status bar, the back arrow in the `UINavigationController` is now set to the application's tintColor rather than the white tintColor I set for the `UINavigationBar`.  This affects other `UINavigationBar` elements throughout the application, such as Add (+) buttons and Edit buttons.  Before displaying the `UIAlertController`, all of the bar button items were showing up as white.

[image: wrong tint color for back button]

[image: wrong tint color for edit and back button]

I'm at a loss here.  My code for displaying the alert is very straightforward:

```
UIAlertController *view = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:VALIDATION_TITLE message:text preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[view addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:VALIDATION_BUTTON_OK style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil]];
[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: when u press ok on alert, the alert dismisses, and then the back arrow is dimmed ? Can you show the code related to the back button ?

Comment: The back arrow isn't actually dimmed; it is set to the global `tintColor` which is greenish/blue.  The back arrow doesn't show that color immediately, but will show the new `tintColor` when I toggle away and back to the screen via the tab bar at the bottom.  There really isn't any code related to the back button... it is a regular `UINavigationController`.

Comment: is it happened after u dismiss the alert ?

Comment: Yes, but again not until I navigate away from my view controller and back to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when dealing with diplaying `UIAlertControllers` when I don't have a handle to the displaying `UIViewController`, I found the following code on stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30941356/3434545

If I use the `show:` method, which invokes a new `UIWindow` and presents the `UIAlertController` from that new window, I don't have any of the UI side effects that I see above when displaying an alert.

If someone knows why this is happening, please still answer this question because this is a fairly hacky workaround!