# Changing orientation in iOS8 with a UIAlertController displayed makes my app's background full black and then rotates

Tags: ios

[image]I have built an iOS app from xcode 7.3.1 and ran it on a iOS 8.4.1 device. When I rotate the device with a UIAlertController is displayed, the background becomes full black (Only component which is visible is the Alert view) and then rotates.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Do you have some warnings/errors in console?

Comment: Can you post how you call the alert and if you have some code in the rotation delegates?

Comment: I have presented exactly like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554894/how-to-present-uialertcontroller-when-not-in-a-view-controller