# Do alert views need to be presented from the top view controller?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

When presenting an `UIAlertController` is it necessary to use the top most `UIViewcontroller` on the screen? Does this `UIViewController` need to be visible or just in the view hierarchy? 
Would there be any disadvantage if presenting any alert directly from the `UIWindow`'s root viewController?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Well, it works, but I'm asking if works in all cases - i.e. if additional logic is required.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion there is nothing wrong in presenting from the root view controller of the application. Take a look at the following question and the accepted answer
[How to present UIAlertController when not in a view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554894/how-to-present-uialertcontroller-when-not-in-a-view-controller)

I've used a category on UIAlertViewController similar to what have been proposed in the answers in the above link, and I've never faced any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to present the `UIAlertViewController` from the currently presented view controller. For me I used to get the currently presented view controller like this:

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
UIViewController *viewController = keyWindow.rootViewController;
while (viewController.presentedViewController) {
    viewController = viewController.presentedViewController;
}
[viewController presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil]
```

Using the root to present the view controller caused an issue for me before but I can't remember actually. You're at the safe side while using the top most one.