# xcode 8 convert project to swift 3 - DBAlertController errors

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, swift3

I'm trying to convert an app built in swift 2.2 with xCode 7.4. I'm now using xCode 8.1 and have updated all pods to the latest versions. Next I converted all code to swift 3. All went well except I have 6 compiler errors for the DBAlertController framework.

On looking at the github page it looks like DBAlertController doesn't support swift 3. I'm very new to xCode/swift development so not sure what's happening here. I originally didn't set a version in my Podfile and it installed version 0.2.6. I set the version to 0.3.0 after seeing this on the github page but I still get the compiler errors and the error below on running pod install. My cocoapods version is 1.2.0.beta.1.

Any ideas on fixing or replacing greatly appreciated.

```
[!] There are duplicate dependencies on `DBAlertController` in `Podfile`:

- DBAlertController (~> 0.3.0)
- DBAlertController
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your code to `Swift 2.3`.

Also, instead of using `DBAlertController`, you can simply show alert yourself. In `Swift 3.0`, you can show alert as :

```
let alertController: UIAlertController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Or you can do something like this :

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
//...
var rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
if let navigationController = rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
    rootViewController = navigationController.viewControllers.first
}
if let tabBarController = rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
    rootViewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController
}
rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Look into this [stackoverflow's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554894/how-to-present-uialertcontroller-when-not-in-a-view-controller) for details