# Warning: Attempt to present UIAlertController on UISplitViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

The issue in most questions similar to this one is that `present` is called before `viewDidAppear`. That is not the reason here.

This app does not use Storyboards of NIBs, and all operations are programmatic.

The `rootViewController` of the window of the app is a `UISplitViewController`. The view controllers of the split view are set to an array of two `UINavigationController`s. A child view controller then modally presents a view controller. The problem is that `UIAlertController`s presented from the app delegate won't show while a view controller is being modally presented. It works otherwise.

How I try to present:

```
window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I get this error:

```
Attempt to present UIAlertController on UISplitViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this, I put this function in my app delegate.

```
// Utility function to avoid:
// Warning: Attempt to present * on * whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
func showAlertGlobally(_ alert: UIAlertController) {
    let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert
    alertWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
    alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
    alertWindow.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: A quite similar solution was proposed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34487871/1187415, for Swift 3 here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40401936/1187415.