# UIAlertController Issues in External Event Driven Presentations

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uialertview, uialertcontroller

We're currently migrating from the deprecated `UIAlertView` to `UIAlertController`.

Our application can react the certain external events (such as push notifications, bluetooth communication, background network responses) and as a result of those events it can present at any moment a new `UIViewController` on top of the top most view controller.

However, since migrating to `UIAlertController`, we've encountered scenarios where an `UIAlertController` is presented right before another `UIViewController` should be presented, since they are triggered by different events.

Since we're relying on the top most view controller, this means that the `UIAlertController` will present another `UIViewController` instance, which isn't what we want, because the `UIAlertController` is not visible any longer.

Is there a way to keep presenting the `UIAlertController` at the window level, just like the deprecated `UIAlertView` works?

In this way we would make sure that the `UIAlertController` is always on top and it can't actually present another `UIViewController`.

Thank you,
Cosmin

Comment: I’ve found something interesting - it seems that this library takes the approach of subclassing UIAlertController an creating a new window - https://github.com/sspbond007/JSAlertView/blob/master/JSAlertView/JSAlertView/JSAlertView.m . I'll look more into it.

Comment: In the end I've taken the UIAlertController extension approach, that uses a dedicated UIWindow runtime property from here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554894/how-to-present-uialertcontroller-when-not-in-a-view-controller This can be closed a a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to present UIAlertController when not in a view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554894/how-to-present-uialertcontroller-when-not-in-a-view-controller)