# Present alert controller on top of a view, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uialertcontroller

I have a view which is subview of a keyWindow (as you can see in the below code). I would like to show an alertController on top of this view (`myView`).

I tried to present alertController on the topViewController (as you can see below), this did not work since the view I have is not part of the topViewController.

How can I present alertController on top of a view ?

This is how I added a view to the keyWindow

```
guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else{
    return
}

window.addSubview(myView)
```

The below did not work since the view is not part of the topViewController.

```
guard let vc = UIApplication.topViewController() else { return}
vc.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: check at this answer. this can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46915716/8294374

Comment: you should present it on the current key-window's root-view-controller, that is always visible and it is always on the top.

Comment: @eneadume, it works thanks..

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
func showAlertMessage(title:String? = nil, _ message:String) {
    let rootVC = APP_DELEGATE.window?.topMostController()
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: message, message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    if let title = title {
        alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    }
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default, handler: nil))
    rootVC?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}