# which identifier is use in place of "present" in alert in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, presentviewcontroller

When I am using alert in swift at the line of present alert I get this error use of unresolved identifier.

File name : **CommonFunctions.swift**

class name : **class CommonFunctions : NSObject**

I am using this code

```
class func gotoSettingScreen()
{
    let alertController = UIAlertController (title: "Title", message: "Go to Settings?", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default) { (_) -> Void in
        guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) else {
            return
        }

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                    print("Settings opened: \(success)") // Prints true
                })
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }
    }
    alertController.addAction(settingsAction)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)


    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Line Error Come :`present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Error is : [image]

Thanks for your help ! and Appreciation !

Comment: are you writing this code in App Delegate ?

Comment: @UmarFarooque No, i create one object type (class CommonFunctions : NSObject)  and filename (basic.swift)

Comment: check my answer.. it should help..

Comment: You should try executing present alert controller from Main queue it should work

Answer (score 1):

`present(_:animated:completion:)` is an [instance method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present) of `UIViewController` and derived types (like `UINavigationController`). So calling it from `class` (static) function of some random class will of course fail.

So what you have here is design issue.

Workaround to call alert from anywhere in the app:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: .alert)
//...
var rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
if let navigationController = rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
    rootViewController = navigationController.viewControllers.first
}
if let tabBarController = rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
    rootViewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController
}
rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Depending on your UI architecture, you can remove unneeded checks.

<sub>Suggested code snippet taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554894/how-to-present-uialertcontroller-when-not-in-a-view-controller).</sub>

Comment: Hexfire Thank you ! and i create one object type (class CommonFunctions : NSObject) and filename (basic.swift) i am using like so..

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

> You need a reference for the ViewController where you wanna show the
>   alert. Since you are using a custom class, NSObject: CommonFunctions,
>   when you wanna show the alert, you need to either pass in the instance
>   of view controller or set the view controller as one of the properties
>   of the CommonFunctions class.

Example:

```
// Basic.Swift 
......

var viewController : UIViewController?
```

When calling the method to show the alert, set the view controller property to the current instance like

```
CommonFunctions.viewController = self
```

You would have to modify your CommonFunctions's `getSettingScreen()` function to use

```
viewController.present()
```

instead of `present()`

This should help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use alert from non uiviewcontroller u can pass uiviewcontroller instance form method like

**Method in NonUicontroller class**

```
func alertDilog(viewController :UIViewController)
{
   let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
            (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            print("OK")
   alertController.addAction(okAction)
        vc.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
        }
```

**To use alertDialog in UiViewcontrollerclass**

```
yourclassName.alertDilog(viewController :self)
```