# How to present a view from AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboard, appdelegate

## I'm currently having some difficulty presenting a view when my 3dTouch shortcut item is activated.

I'm attempting to present a view when the user uses the shortcut item 'Add Note'.

When activating the 'Add Note' shortcut item my application crashes and gives me the error: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Here is the code: (App Delegate)

```
var cVC = ContainerVCViewController()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    if shortcutItem.type == "DarthDevelopments.noteapp.addNote" {
        //Prefrom Action Go To Add Note View
        cVC.anim1in()
    }

    if shortcutItem.type == "$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER).createList" {
        //Prefrom Action Go To Create List View Controller

    }
}
```

Here is the code: (ContainerVCViewController)

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var notesLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var addNoteView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var addNoteText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var blurView: UIVisualEffectView!

func anim1in() {
    blurView.isHidden = false

    view.addSubview(addNoteView)
    addNoteView.center = self.view.center
    addNoteView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    addNoteView.alpha = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
    self.addNoteView.alpha = 1
    self.addNoteView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }
}
```

While debugging I can see that while calling `cVC.anim1in()` all the IBOutlets are equal to nil.

Here is what I'm receiving from the console:

[Console Log Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpuCX.png)

**Note:**

I've been going over this for quite a while and I have come up with these conclusions:

- I need to be able to initialize all the IBOutlets
- Find a new method of presenting the 'AddNote View'

**If anyone can come up with a solution to one of these ideas or another solution, that would be great!**

**I’m somewhat of a new developer. Sorry if I'm making a silly mistake.**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time,

DarthShmev.

**Important:**

I've come up with somewhat of a solution thanks to *Agility Vision*.

Here is the post: [StackOverFlow Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554894/how-to-present-uialertcontroller-when-not-in-a-view-controller)

What he is basically saying is that I would need to:

- Create a *UIWindow* with a transparent *UIViewController* and then presenting the view on it.

**I'm not sure to how to apply this in my situation though.**

Comment: The default initializer `()` creates a new instance of the view controller which is **not** the instance in the storyboard. You need the *real* reference. As `AppDelegate` is accessible from everywhere you could save a reference (or a callback closure) to  the actual `ContainerVCViewController` when it's presented the first time. Or you could send a notification.

Comment: Could you please give an **example** of how I'd apply this.