# UIAlertController does not dismiss properly on iPhone 8 device

Tags: ios, iphone, uialertcontroller, ios12

The issue is `UIAlertVIewController` does not work properly on iPhone 8 or iPhone 6 with iOS 12.
I need to display alert when not in a view controller and using below reference I’m able to do display alert

[How to present UIAlertController when not in a view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554894/how-to-present-uialertcontroller-when-not-in-a-view-controller)

But when I tap on “OK” alert dismiss but the gray colored background does not go off, we have to kill the app only.Attached screenshot.
[image]

Same code works good in iPhone X, not sure what could be wrong in below code.

```
UIAlertController *alertvc = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Device Registeration Error" message:"Device Error" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[alertvc addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}]];   
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.rootViewController presentViewController:alertvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

After tapping "OK" the grey background of the alert still exist, it does not go off, don't know where code is wrong.

Comment: Try to change the `handler` of the `UIAlertAction` to `nil`.

Comment: @Yonat - adding nil also did not work