# How to handle multiple UIAlertControllers in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, uialertcontroller

I have to show multiple UIAlerts in one viewController before iOS8 we can use the UIAlerts with tags and we can identify in clickedButtonAtIndex using tags like.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if(alertView.tag == 1)
{
//UIAlert1 button clicked
}

if(alertView.tag == 2)
{
//UIAlert2 button clicked
}
}
```

so we can do stuff. 
how to identify button clicks of different UIAlertControllers.
Because one alert1 button click i have to change the some text color and alert2 button click i have to pop the view controller.

Comment: this is a good question

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38875376/3412051

Answer (score 1):

`UIAlertController` is block-based.

Create an `UIAlertAction` instance for each action and pass the block to be executed after the button is tapped.

For further information read the [UIAlertController "review"](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/) of Mattt Thompson.

Comment: Yes i can pass the block to be executed for the button action. Like i have two alerts with buttons like cancel and done, cancel and save. When user click on done i have to do one functionality and when user click on save i have to do other functinality.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following way.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 {
  if(alertView.tag == 1)
    {
      //UIAlert1 button clicked
         if(buttonIndex==0){//say, **Cancel** button tag
            //alert2 "Cancel" button has tapped
          }else if(buttonIndex==1){say, **OK** button tag
            //alert2 "OK" button has tapped
           }
    }

  if(alertView.tag == 2)
    {
      //UIAlert2 button clicked
      if(buttonIndex==0){//say, **Yes** button tag
           //alert2 "YES" button has tapped
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: This delegate method is for use with UIAlertView, though isn't used with UIAlertController, which has taken over from UIAlertview and UIActionSheet as from iOS8

Comment: @jamil65able From iOS8 onwards we cant use the UIAlertView.